# What is the best way to get values from a ColdFusion QueryBean with C#

Tags: c#, coldfusion

I am having to call a ColdFusion web service which returns a QueryBean. Which returns a set of complex arrays that have the values I am looking for. When I make the call I get all the data in the arrays that I am expecting but now I am trying to get to the data and it keeps telling me that I am missing something or I can't use indexing with an object.

I created a web reference called DAM_Search in VS2010 and I call it with this command;

```
DAM_Folder.folderService obj_Folder = new DAM_Folder.folderService();
DAM_Folder.QueryBean qBean = bj_Folder.getfolder("1-Key", str_Folder_ID);
```

What I get back is qBean which contains 4 arrays in it, with the first two arrays are

```
qBean.columnList[10]
qBean.columnListField[10]
```

and contain the names of the fields that are used in the data rows.   Next it has

```
qBean.data[4]
qBean.dataField[4]
```

This is where the data is returned. In the example above the qBean in returning 4 rows of data. The data is in an array with the values of the columns named in the `columnList[10]`.

I figure that since a picture is worth a 1000 words, this might help.

[image: qBean Capture]
<sub>(source: [sapp-family.com](http://sapp-family.com/forums/qBean_Capture.jpg))</sub>

What I am trying to do now is get the data from the internal array of `qBean.data[0][0]`. In the Immediate Window when I try `? qBean.data[0]` it returns the correct array of values.

I have tried the following

```
? qBean.data[0][0] 
"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

? qBean.data[0].[0]
Identifier expected

? qBean.data[0,0]
Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 1
```

So, my fellow Stackoverflow users, what do I need to do for getting the values of this object?  I figure it's something simple and I am just over thinking it, but it is just driving me up a wall right now.

Comment: Because CF numbers arrays from 1, it's not letting you treat these as arrays. My guess is that they're actually stored as structs.  Can you try passing in the "0" as a string? Like...qBean.data["0"].["0"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I got side tracked and did not go back and update the original question with a work around.  Sorry about that...

My solution to the issue is to cast the `qBean.Data[0]` as an `IEnumerable` object. I then run it through a `foreach` loop which feeds the data into an array that I can pass back to the calling function. For example;

```
string[] FileData = new string[0];            
foreach (var var_Value in (IEnumerable)qBean.data[0])
        {
            Array.Resize<string>(ref FileData, FileData.Length + 1);
            FileData[FileData.Length-1] = var_Value.ToString();
        }
```

Now that I know this works, I am going to pull a count from the other array in the QueryBean and set the `FileData[]` size before I start the `foreach` so I don't have to copy the array 21 times with the `Array.Resize<>`.  While at the moment the data I am working with is small, I never know what it's going to be in the future.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I would try qBean.data[0][0].toSting()

Comment: I tried it, I get the error;

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

As you can see, it's actually an array of objects and not an array of strings.  I think I found a work around though, see my updates to the original post.